# How to perform PAM algorithm without creating the copy of clusters for each swap?

Tags: machine-learning, time-complexity, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to implement the PAM algorithm. During the swap stage I need to find the most optimal swap between a pair of elements (medoid, nonmedoid). My initial idea for assessing the quality of a swap was calculating total dispersion before and after the swap and looking for the highest delta value in order to elect the best pair of elements. This, however, requires me to create a copy of the whole system for every pair, which might become really slow for large datasets.

For cluster representation I am using a Map, where medoids are mapped to a List of nonmedoids (a cluster that they constitute).

Is there a more efficient way to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

That will be horribly slow.

Do a complexity analysis of your approach. PAM is supposed to be O(k (n-k)²). There is the loop over all medoids and all non-medoids. That leaves you O(n-k) to compute the cost of the swap.

PAM computes the *change* in clustering quality directly to achieve this. You may need to study it more closely - don't rely on Wikipedia quality summaries that focus on the primary idea, not all the details. Instead, read the book by Kaufman and Rousseauw.

Comment: Could you provide the title of said book?

Comment: I don't remember the title. The book where the algorithm PAM is from. Wikipedia probably knows.